# Git merging multiple branches with slashes in name

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

I'm trying to merge multiple branches I've created into one single branch. The branches are named like so: desktop/stack, desktop/account etc...

I want to merge them into desktop/master, however it says it is already up to date. Is it because they all share the desktop name? If that's the case, are any of the branches truly separated?

If they are all merged, and the same branch anyways, whats the point of separating the names?

EDIT:

I'm just using terminal and checked out a new branch called desktop/master, then used git merge desktop/account. I get the Already Up To Date message.

Comment: Can you show us the Git commands you used to merge?  If you are doing this from a plugin (like eGit), then how did you go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I see only two possibilities here:

1) The `desktop/master` branch really is up to date, and merging it with `desktop/account` would bring in no new changes, or

2) You need to update the `desktop/account` branch *before* you try to merge it into `desktop/master`.  If this be the case, then the following should do the trick:

```
git pull origin desktop/account
git checkout master
git merge desktop/account
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how git works. If I started with desktop/stack and in between made all sorts of commits and changes, created new branches such as desktop/account etc... would my newest branch desktop/master contain all those new additions, and therefore be up-to-date?

Comment: Let's take a step back.  Try doing this: `git checkout desktop/master` followed by `git log`.  Repeat for `desktop/account`.  See if the commits are the same.

Comment: yea all of my desktop/... have all the same commits

Comment: Assuming you have tried pulling from the remote _and_ they really have the same commits in the same order, then these branches are the same.  Check with the owners of these branches.  Maybe they recently branched and have not yet pushed.